# Select UITextField while animating background color

Tags: swift, uiview, uitextfield, core-animation, uiviewanimation

How do I animate the TextField without disabling it?

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                    (self.phoneCell.subviews[1].subviews[1] as! UITextField).layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
                }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

To allow user interaction for your `UITextField` during animation, you need to add the option `.allowUserInteraction`:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0,
    options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .curveEaseInOut, .allowUserInteraction],
    animations: {
        self.myTextField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
    }, completion: nil)
```